# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apiclient'

Tags: python, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-client

I am trying to run a python code that will help me in connecting & extracting data from YouTube Data API v3. However, the moment i try to run the code, it give me the following error right at the first line:

```
File "C:/Users/asaxena/Desktop/py4e/Social Media Data Analytics/youtube_search.py", line 3, in <module>
    from apiclient.discovery import build
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apiclient'
```

I have already installed google-api-python-client in my working directory through the command: pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client 
But its not helping me in running the code.

```py
from apiclient.discovery import build
import argparse
import csv
import unidecode

def youtube_search(options):
    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
    search_response = youtube.search().list(q=options.q, part="id,snippet", maxResults=options.max_results).execute()

    videos = []
    channels = []
    playlists = []

    csvFile = open('video_result.csv','w')
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
    csvWriter.writerow(["title","videoId","viewCount","likeCount","dislikeCount","commentCount","favoriteCount"])

    for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
        if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
            title = search_result["snippet"]["title"]
            title = unidecode.unidecode(title)  # Dongho 08/10/16
            videoId = search_result["id"]["videoId"]
            video_response = youtube.videos().list(id=videoId,part="statistics").execute()
            for video_result in video_response.get("items",[]):
                viewCount = video_result["statistics"]["viewCount"]
                if 'likeCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                    likeCount = 0
                else:
                    likeCount = video_result["statistics"]["likeCount"]
                if 'dislikeCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                    dislikeCount = 0
                else:
                    dislikeCount = video_result["statistics"]["dislikeCount"]
                if 'commentCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                    commentCount = 0
                else:
                    commentCount = video_result["statistics"]["commentCount"]
                if 'favoriteCount' not in video_result["statistics"]:
                    favoriteCount = 0
                else:
                    favoriteCount = video_result["statistics"]["favoriteCount"]

            csvWriter.writerow([title,videoId,viewCount,likeCount,dislikeCount,commentCount,favoriteCount])

    csvFile.close()
```

At the end, I should be able to establish a successful connection with YouTube Data API v3, and extract data in a csv file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're importing a non-existing module. According to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started) you should be using:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import ...
```

instead of:

```
from apiclient.discovery import ...
```

Comment: It doesn't work with "googleapiclient" as well; now it shows me the error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'"

Answer (score 1):

I solved it:

1. I manually installed the "google-api-python-client-master" separately in my working directory and then ran: "setup.py install" from the command line.
2. I then manually installed "Unidecode-master" separately within the unzipped "google-api-python-client-master" folder and then ran: "setup.py install" from the command line.
3. I then ran the above code, and it worked.

I believe you would have to install the API folders separately, or it won't work. Hope this is useful.